# Problems with HelloMapView tutorial

Tags: android, google-maps, android-context

In the [HelloMapView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html), the map seems to load fine, I can see maps, and also I can see the mark of Mexico that the example gives.

But, when I click on the Mexico mark, my application crashes, with the message

> Android application crash

I think that I know what the problem is but I don't know how to solve it:

In step 7, the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) says this:

> Now set up the ability to handle touch events on the overlay items. First, you're going to need a reference to the application Context as a member of this class. So add Context mContext as a class member, then initialize it with a new class constructor:

```
public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
  super(defaultMarker);
  mContext = context;
}
```

Okay, but in the main tutorial class, when it declares this class, it doesn't give it the context:

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
```

I tried to do this: `new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, getApplicationContext());`

but that does not work, the map appears without the Mexico mark.

Does anyone have an idea of where I went wrong?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at LogCat and examine the stack trace associated with your "android application crash". Also, do not use `getApplicationContext()` for GUI operations -- use `this` instead.

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare wrote:

> Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at LogCat and examine the stack trace associated with your "android application crash". Also, do not use `getApplicationContext()` for GUI operations -- use `this` instead.

Comment: ([Question answered n comments. Converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))